# BIMI SVG validation error

Tags: validation, svg, bimi

I have a validation error that I can't seem to fix.

The error is:

> svg:1:133: error: element 'svg' missing required attribute 'baseProfile'

Meanwhile, my SVG tag is:

```
<svg baseProfile="tiny-ps" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 118 118" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

I have a baseProfile defined. What could be causing validation to fail.

Thanks!

Comment: What tool gives this verification error?

Comment: Two, thank you: the MX Toolbox one and BIMIgroup.org both produce the same error. 

Using RNC Schema validation, I don't get any errors. But in testing, the logo doesn't appear.

Comment: Maybe try https://bimigroup.org/svg-conversion-tools-released/ and see how the resulting SVG differs from yours, it might give clues. Otherwise no specific idea but difficult to assess without the full file. I suspect `1:133` means line 1 column 133 in your file (but that can as well be something completely different), but your string has only 99 characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I used all the SVG conversion tools listed and still it failed validation.

It turns out that Wordpress was stripping the baseProfile tag from the SVG file, causing it to fail validation. I'm not sure if it is something specific to this installation of Wordpress (or some plugin) or if it's a generally issue, but I'll leave this here for future reference.

I uploaded the SVG via SCP and now everything works.

Comment: Please select your answer as the correct answer